# Is there any way to get rid of pixel bleed happening in UV Bakes that occur along the seams of an object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, baking, denoise

I'm trying to bake a 4096x4096 image of my object (diffuse, normal, rough, ambient occlusion) and I'm using a UV that can't be changed (meant to be uploaded to a game tool) and whenever I'm baking, I wind up with pixels bleeding along the seams of the faces within the object. I have tried upscaling the bake image and it still occurs, just with smaller sets of pixels but the same general issue. I also have the denoise option disabled for Render and have tried increasing the pixel Margin all to no avail. For now I am manually cleaning up the resultant images in post but this is a problem for all my bake types, and some are harder than others to clean up (Normal and AO mostly). Any tips would be appreciated. This is in Blender 3.4.1 as well. Thanks.
[image] [image] [image]